# Is it possible to obtain batch size in keras layer

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm design a specific keras layer using lambda function,how can I get the dynamic `batch_size` in the function?

I tried many times to solve this problem,but all failed.

```py
def minus(inputs):
    x,y = inputs
    batch_size=K.shape(x)[0]
    e = K.get_variable_shape(x)
    for k in range(e[0]):
        for i in range(e[1]):
            for j in range(e[2]):
                if x[k][i][j]==0:
                   K.update(x[k][i][j], y[k][i][j])
    return x

def mymodel():
    inpA = keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,8),name='InputLayerA')
    inpB = keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,8),name='InputLayerB')
    print(inpA.shape)
    middle = keras.layers.Lambda(minus,name='minus')([inpA,inpB])

    ae = keras.Model([inpA,inpB],middle)
    ae.summary()
    return ae
```

When I new a model,like `ae = mymodel()` .I except a new x tensor,but the actual is error message:`'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using tensorflow I am using tf.shape(x) to get the batch-size for model layers, so I think you are right that K.shape(x) (keras equivalent?) can be used.

If i understand what you try to do correct, wouldn't this be sufficient? With the bonus of avoiding slow python for-loops.

```py
import keras
import keras.backend as K

def minus(inputs):
    x,y = inputs
    change_index = K.cast(K.equal(x, 0),'float32')
    return x*(1-change_index)+y*change_index

def mymodel():
    inpA = keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,8),name='InputLayerA')
    inpB = keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,8),name='InputLayerB')
    print(inpA.shape)
    middle = keras.layers.Lambda(minus,name='minus')([inpA,inpB])

    ae = keras.Model([inpA,inpB],middle)
    ae.summary()
    return ae

ae = mymodel()
```

Comment: Awesome！！Thanks for your answer，you save me from another sleepless night~